# How to create a 3-D state (array) of qubits in qiskit or cirq etc?

Tags: qiskit, programming, cirq

I want a 3-D cube-like array for state of qubits, on which I want further to implement different sets of rotations, etc, for cryptographic means. You can [create a 2D grid qubit in cirq](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/GridQubit) with `GridQubit`. But is there a method to create a 3D array for qubits?

Comment: Have a look at how Pasqal implemented their 3D qubit: https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/cirq-pasqal/cirq_pasqal/pasqal_qubits.py - or you can use it directly.

Comment: @BalintPato Thanks for the code, Yes, I was looking for something like this. Hope, it works for my model.